# Encoding in emacs mysql buffer

Tags: mysql, emacs, encoding, ssh

I seem to be having trouble with my mysql buffer, which i use to connect to a database containing latin1 data, over a ssh-connection.

```
live [db]> show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Displaying data stored in database poses no problem:

```
live [db]> SELECT title FROM manual limit 4,1;
+----------+
| title    |
+----------+
| Allmänt |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

(notice the ä).

However, when I try to input something to the database, it is not correctly encoded. For example:

```
live [db]> SELECT 'ä' ;
+--+
|  |
+--+
|  |
+--+
```

If I ssh in to the server containing the database, and connect directly with the mysql client, I don't have this problem.